# Complex quadratic equation having one purely imaginary root

Tags: complex-numbers

> Question: If $a$ is a complex number such that $\vert a\vert=1$, then find the values of $a$ such that the equation $az^2+z+1=0$ has one purely imaginary root.

The equation can be written as $$z^2+\bar{a}z+\bar{a}=0$$
$$z=-\frac{\bar{a}}{2}\pm\sqrt{\frac{\bar{a}^2}{4}-\bar{a}}$$
that did not work. So I tried using the sum andproduct of the roots:

Let the roots be $x$ and $ki$.

$$x+ki=-\bar{a}$$
$$xki=\bar a$$
From the second equation,
$$x=-\frac{\bar a}{k}i$$

Substituting $x$ in first equation,
$$k^2-k\bar ai-\bar a=0$$
The above equation should have a real solution for $k$
On using the discriminant formula, I am not getting the correct answer.

Comment: Why will the imaginary root not have a real part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last equation can be obtained by just plugging $ki$ into the original equation. Then starting from here, let $a=a_1+a_2 i$ and equate the real part and imaginary part of the equation with $0$, respectively.

You will then get
$$a_1=\frac{1}{k^2}\\
a_2=\frac{1}{k}$$

Now recall that $|a|=1$. Using this you can solve for $k$.

Answer (score 3):

If $a(ir)^2+ir+1=0$ then $r$ cannot be $0$ and therefore

$$a=\frac{ir+1}{r^2}.$$

If $a$ is on the unit circle then the denominator and numerator must have equal norm, so

$$r^2+1=r^4$$

determines the four possible values of $r.$